# Reversible smoothing of a two dimensional function (or an image)

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, transformation, image-processing

Smoothing of an image, or a two dimensional function is quite easy, there are many methods to achieve it, using average of near elements.

But how to make it reversible?

Maybe DCT (discrete cosine transform) can be used to achieve reversible smoothing of a two dimensional function, but I am not sure exactly how to do it.

Comment: What would DCT be?

Comment: discrete cosine transform

Comment: You can smooth an image $x$ by applying a convolution operator: let $y = Kx$, where $K$ performs a convolution with a Gaussian kernel.  $K$ is often very ill-conditioned, which can prevent you from recovering $x$ using $x = K^{-1} y$.  However, if $K$ is not too ill-conditioned, then this simple approach should work.  In that case, $K^{-1}y$ could be computed using the FFT.